# docker-compose up ошибка Django|Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=DjangoDB
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dias2502
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=DjangoDB
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dias2502
    depends_on:
      - db
```

requirements:

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
psycopg2>=2.8
```

**При docker-compose up :**

```
Attaching to siteauth-db-1, siteauth-web-1
siteauth-web-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
siteauth-web-1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
siteauth-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
siteauth-web-1  |     self.run()
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
siteauth-web-1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
in inner_run
siteauth-web-1  |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception      
siteauth-web-1  |     raise _exception[1]
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in executesiteauth-web-1  |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
siteauth-web-1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
siteauth-web-1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
siteauth-web-1  |     app_config.import_models()
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
siteauth-web-1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
siteauth-web-1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
siteauth-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
siteauth-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
siteauth-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
siteauth-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
siteauth-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
siteauth-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/src/siteAuth/catalog/models.py", line 1, in <module>
siteauth-web-1  |     from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 6, in <module>
siteauth-web-1  |     raise ImportError('win32 only')
siteauth-web-1  | ImportError: win32 only
```

***UPD:***

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from .managers import CustomUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.conf import settings



class NoteUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
class Note(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Создано")

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: В ошибке написано 
siteauth-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 6, in <module>
siteauth-web-1  |     raise ImportError('win32 only')

Вы создаете образ на линуксе. Видимо надо адаптировать код под linux или собирать образ на винде

Comment: @Alpensin недавно начал только изучать Docker, не очень понимаю, что значит собрать образ на винде, если я linux пока даже не трогал, просто выполнял инструкции  https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

Comment: А файл siteAuth/catalog/models.py из примера или свой?
команда FROM python:3 берет образ отсюда https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3/images/sha256-17e2d81e5757980ee40742d77dd5d3e1a69ad0d6dacb13064e1b018a6664ec72?context=explore

А этот образ с питоном в свою очередь построен на образе с операционной системой.
Можешь попробовать выполнить команду docker run -it --rm python:3 для запуска контейнера с питоном.  дальше с помощью import platform; platform.platform() узнать на базе какой ос поднят контейнер.

Comment: @Alpensin вы правы у меня там указан Linux, в этой ситуации мне теперь нужно использовать windows container как я понимаю?

Comment: Или менять код. Код в файле windows_events.py смотрели? Там нельзя не импортировать windows_events? СТранная строчка с импортом 
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL - зачем это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно установить **WSL2** https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install и установить **дистрибутив Linux**, в моем случае это был **Ubuntu из Microsoft Store**.
Запустить консоль Ubuntu

```
mkdir <name>   
code <name>
```

После чего у вас запуститься Visual Studio Code и предложит установить необходимые расширения:

- **Remote - WSL**
- **Remote - Containers**

Проверьте, что в приложении Docker у вас **выбран Linux контейнер**, а не Windows ( ПКМ по иконке Docker, должно быть Switch to Windows containers…  ) и в настройках **выбрано <Use the WSL 2 based engine>** и **выбран ваш дистрибутив Linux** ( Resoursec -> WSL Integration ).
*P.S. Пробовал контейнеры Windows, образы очень много весят, не рекомендую*